# XML to JSON converter xml_str2json returns null?

Tags: xml, angularjs

When I use following code:

```
$http.get("http://246e90f2.tunnel.org.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder").success(function (data) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var jsonData = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                console.log("debug", data);
                console.log("debug", jsonData);
            });
```

jsonData is null, it seems related to my xml output from the link:
http://246e90f2.tunnel.org.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder （link might be unavilable due to ngrok）

```
<response>
<item>
<id>1</id>
<token>gh_9831478f66cb</token>
<order_id>143978240336383</order_id>
<openid>oPuB9wkVKTXn9AZ9idM-XqhUvxh0</openid>
<table_id>0</table_id>
<ctime>1439782403</ctime>
<phone>13211675827</phone>
<address>云南昆明 详细地址</address>
<remark/>
<detail>
{"4":{"num":2,"id":"4","name":"\u86cb\u7092\u996d","price":"10.00","total":20},"6":{"num":1,"id":"6","name":"\u626c\u5dde\u7092\u996d","price":"10.00","total":"10.00"},"5":{"num":1,"id":"5","name":"\u51b0\u6dc7\u51cc","price":"8.00","total":"8.00"}}
</detail>
<name>霆鈞</name>
<processed>0</processed>
<paid>0</paid>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<token>gh_9831478f66cb</token>
<order_id>143979224136359</order_id>
<openid>oPuB9wkVKTXn9AZ9idM-XqhUvxh0</openid>
<table_id>0</table_id>
<ctime>1439792241</ctime>
<phone>13211675827</phone>
<address>云南昆明 详细地址</address>
<remark/>
<detail>
{"4":{"num":1,"id":"4","name":"\u86cb\u7092\u996d","price":"10.00","total":"10.00"}}
</detail>
<name>霆鈞</name>
<processed>0</processed>
<paid>0</paid>
</item>
<item>
<id>3</id>
<token>gh_9831478f66cb</token>
<order_id>143995577636336</order_id>
<openid>oPuB9wkVKTXn9AZ9idM-XqhUvxh0</openid>
<table_id>0</table_id>
<ctime>1439955776</ctime>
<phone>13211675827</phone>
<address>云南昆明 锦苑花园32幢202室</address>
<remark>快点哦</remark>
<detail>
{"5":{"num":2,"id":"5","name":"\u51b0\u6dc7\u51cc","price":"8.00","total":16}}
</detail>
<name>霆鈞</name>
<processed>0</processed>
<paid>0</paid>
</item>
</response>
```

but i've tried following link and my xml is valid:
http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

I want to know where the problem is? thanks.

Comment: Check out this article ~ http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/

Comment: thanks @Phil but it seems still return null when I call xml_str2json for my link.

Comment: Ever resolve this?

Comment: sorry, long time ago, I forgot...

Comment: for me  it works at the first time but now at all. I don't know where is the problem !!

Comment: @IsaacLi do you have anidea about this issue ?